# Set of $(x,t)$ such that $e^{- \frac{|x|^2}{4t}} \geq c$ is compact

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

Let $\phi(x,t) = (4 \pi t)^{-\frac{n}{2}} e^{- \frac{|x|^2}{4t}}$ be the fundamental solution of the heat equation in $\mathbb R^n$. What is the exact reasoning that the set
$\{(x,t) \in \mathbb R^n \times[0,\infty) | \phi(x,t) \geq t^{-\frac{n}{2}}\}$
is compact?
Well, $\phi(x,t) \geq t^{-\frac{n}{2}}$ iff $e^{- \frac{|x|^2}{4t}} \geq (4 \pi)^{\frac{n}{2}}$, a constant. Now why is the set of $(x,t)$ for which this holds compact? What is the analytic property of the function $e^{- \frac{|x|^2}{4t}}$ to assure this? I mean I can picture it that this function is concentrated near $0$ but how to argue mathematical here?

Comment: If $t=A|x|^2/4$ where $A$ is such that $e^{-1/A}\geqslant (4\pi)^{n/2}$, then $(t,x)$ lies in $\{(x,t) \in \mathbb R^n \times[0,\infty) | \phi(x,t) \geq t^{-\frac{n}{2}}\}$. Hence $(\sqrt A(j,\dots,j)/2,j)$ belongs to this set. As a consequence, it cannot be bounded hence compact.

Comment: But the point $(\sqrt A(j,...,j)/2,j)$ (or do you rather mean $2(j,...,j)/\sqrt A,j)$?) does not satisfy $t = A|x|^2/4$

Comment: I was not careful enough for the constants. Anyway, your set is not bounded.

Answer (score 0):

Let $$S:=\left\{(x,t) \in \mathbb R^n \times[0,\infty) | \phi(x,t) \geq t^{-\frac{n}{2}}\right\}.$$
Observe that if $(x,t)\in C$, then $\left(\lambda x,\lambda^2t\right)$ belongs to $S$ for any positive $\lambda$. Therefore, $S$ is not bounded and cannot be compact.